# cannot select MOI in couchbase server setting

Tags: couchbase, sql++

I have just installed Couchbase Community 4.5 server.
I want to enable MOI index but I get both radio button disable. I can't click or choose them. see below screen shot

[image]

How I can make them enable ?
How i can choose MOI?
when I installed same things there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MOI is an EE feature. You can find the CE vs EE differences at
https://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/4.5/introduction/editions.html
or
https://www.couchbase.com/nosql-databases/downloads